# multiprocessing: using pool inside imported function

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to create a script where it calls a function from a seperate module to do parallel processing.

My 'top-level' script looks like this:

```
from hydrology import model, descriptors
if __name__ == "__main__":
   datafile = r"C:\folder\datafile.shp"
   myModel = model.Model(data = datafile)

   res = descriptors.watershed_pll(myModel)
```

The `descriptors` module looks like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from arcfunc import multi_watershed

def watershed_pll(model):
    pool = Pool()
    for key, val in model.stations.iteritems():
        res = pool.apply_async(multi_watershed(val, key))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return res
```

As you can see, the function to run in parallel is imported from the module `arcfunc`,
the function carrying out the parallelisation is inside the module `descriptors` and the script running everything is seperate again.

There are no exceptions when I run, but I have two problems:

1. res.successful() returns False
2. It runs no quicker than without multiprocessing.

I suspect that my architecture is complicating things, however, it is important that the parallelisation function is in a separate module.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the function and argument to `apply_async`, the code calls `multi_watershed` directly (in main process), and pass the return value of the function.

Pass the function and arguments.

Replace following line:

```
res = pool.apply_async(multi_watershed(val, key))
```

with:

```
res = pool.apply_async(multi_watershed, (val, key))
```

Comment: duh! Thanks. Well, it works, but I still have the problem that it is no faster. This may be something to do with the external library in use: arcpy....

Comment: @jramm, Sorry, but I don't know about arcpy.